# How VMWare Snapshot "Save" VM's state without copying all the VM files?

Tags: vmware

I was wondering, what kind of technique VMware Snapshots uses to assure that you will be able to return to a previous state without copying all the VM's disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is basically a delta child disk. Operations are made it it while running off the snapshot. Makes it easy to revert.

[link to explanation](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1015180)